# How to edit a binary at specific address locations using Nim?

Tags: binary, nim-lang

I'm trying to understand how to modify a Windows executable using Nim to write NOPs in specific locations of the file. In Python I do this as follows:

```
    with open('file.exe', 'r+b') as f:
        f.seek(0x0014bc0f)
        f.write(binascii.unhexlify('9090'))
        f.seek(0x0014bc18)
        f.write(binascii.unhexlify('9090'))
```

But in Nim I can't find the necessary methods to accomplish the seeking to a specific address and how to input these op-codes properly. I'm pretty new to Nim and the different file operation possibilities are a little confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/io.html) for io are quite good, but to start you off:

- opening a file for reading and writing (equivalent of 'r+') is:

```
let f = open("file.exe",fmReadWriteExisting)
```

- the equivalent of `with` here, to make sure to close the file on any error:

```
defer: f.close
```

- seeking to an offset (by default bytes relative to the start):

```
f.setFilePos(0x014bc0f)
```

- writing two bytes at that position (nop nop)

```
f.write("\x90\x90")
```

check out the documentation for each proc for more options

Comment: Thank you very much. Got it working now. I thought I tried these already but evidently not correctly. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow and welcome to the Nim community :-)